# Create anchor tag in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm creating anchor tag as:

```
 var link = $('<a/>').text("Forget password").attr('href', '/Account/ForgetPassword');
```

and using it in jquery as:

```
 $error = "Incorrect password." + link + " ?";
```

and using it in html as: (I'm using knockout)

```
<div data-bind="text:error"></div>
```

But the output is:

```
Incorrect password.[object Object] ?
```

How can I get the output as a link?

**Update:**
I have used this:

```
$error = "Incorrect password." + link[0].outerHTML + " ?";
```

Now the output is:

```
Incorrect password.<a href="/Account/ForgetPassword">Forget password</a> ?
```

How to render this as html?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html

Answer (score 3):

You have to use its `outerHTML` property of Jquery object's underneath node object,

```
$error = "Incorrect password." + link[0].outerHTML + " ?";
```

You are simply concatenating the object. So its primitive value is getting concatenated.

Comment: Not working as expected. Output is `Incorrect password.<a href="/Account/ForgetPassword">Forget password</a> ?`

Comment: @IrfanWattoo What do you expect? Can't you render that as a html?

Comment: how to render that as html?